# How can I ignore bus errors in dvgrab?

Tags: video-recording, firewire

I'm using dvgrab to digitize a bunch of 19+ year old MiniDV cassettes.  I've successfully used it to record about 15-18 tapes without issue, but I've got 3-4 tapes that result in a bus error almost immediately.

```
dvgrab -timestamp --size 0 --rewind GigglingIan-
Found AV/C device with GUID 0x0000850001004b8e
Waiting for DV...
Capture Started
Bus error
```

Meanwhile, in dmesg, I get some useful debugging info, but nothing that really points to a workaround:

```
[12337.326105] traps: dvgrab[24054] trap stack segment ip:7f110ddeed36 sp:7f110650bbb0 error:0 in libdv.so.4.0.3[7f110ddeb000+13000]
[20256.965238] traps: dvgrab[24380] trap stack segment ip:7fd02152cd36 sp:7fd019c49bb0 error:0 in libdv.so.4.0.3[7fd021529000+13000]
```

The man page doesn't offer very many suggestions.  Has anyone hit this particular issue and figured out a workaround?

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details (*allowing specific advice*); but have you tried changing the log level (*result will affect all apps*)

Comment: Likely the media is corrupt and dvgrab has bugs that cause it to crash while attempting to decode corrupted media.  Even if it didn't crash, there will be corruption in the copied media.